# Send async email about destroyed objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In rails I have often had to send an email to someone about something that has been deleted. The issue is that when writing en asynchronously email the object has been deleted before the email is generated.

I usually only add integers and strings as parameters, just like sidekiq suggests. I thought about doing this:

```
mail = MyMailer.some_mail(recipient_id, deleted_object_id)
mail.delay.deliver
```

But this is not recommended either: **avoiding delaying methods on instances**

---

I've also considered 2 other options, but I don't like them at all.

1. Use acts_as_paranoid, setting a deleted_at field on the record instead of delete from db.
2. Render the email body, save to db and send later

Any suggestions to a propper way to solve this?

Comment: for what reason you need to send email? If you have to confirm and is a option undo the delete maybe the paranoid is a good option. But if is only to notify I think the option is to save the text only (email body or some like thata)

Comment: You can use your first option, and you can schedule a job to run every three days or every week (or whatever you want), and that job would look for those records with `deleted_at <= 1.week.ago` and delete those old records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting an object and sending an email is such tightly coupled, you can create a sidekiq job which does both things. So you have only to send an id to the job. The sidekiq job deletes your object and sends the email synchronous, within the job. For your request the mail is still send asynchron.

Comment: I Like the idea. The only thing I think is unfortunate is that the user who triggered the delete will still see the object because it the job has probably not been executed yet. Maybe the 'deleted_at' option is the way to go after all.